# Why my java project doesn't run? I' using maven but it doesn't find the plugin

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm triyng to run  a  in project NetBeans but it doesn't compile. I think its because of the `settings.xml` file but I'm not sure.
When compiling I get this:

```
cd C:\Users\Paulo Sérgio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\consulta-postos-master; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1" cmd /c "\"C:\\Users\\Paulo Sérgio\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\consulta-postos-master\\mvnw.cmd\" -Dexec.vmArgs= \"-Dexec.args=${exec.vmArgs} -classpath %classpath ${exec.mainClass} ${exec.appArgs}\" -Dexec.appArgs= -Dexec.mainClass=${start-class} \"-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-18.0.1.1\\bin\\java.exe\" \"-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-13\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec"
Scanning for projects...

-------------------< com.faculdade:consulta-postos >--------------------
Building consulta-postos 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ consulta-postos ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource
Copying 5 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ consulta-postos ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 67 source files to C:\Users\Paulo Sérgio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\consulta-postos-master\target\classes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  29.809 s
Finished at: 2022-06-21T19:12:00-03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project consulta-postos: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x70697478) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x70697478 -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: `To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`   <--- Do these.  Look at the output, and see if it helps you understand the problem.

Comment: But it looks like you are using a version of Java (18!?!) that the Lombok plugin does not support.  Judging from the [Lombok change log](https://projectlombok.org/changelog), you will need Lombok v1.18.24 ... and associated maven plugin version.

Comment: But the latest plugin is [v1.18.18.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok-maven-plugin/1.18.18.0/maven-plugin), so the issue may be that Java 18 support is ... lacking ... in the Lombok world.  (Try Java 17 LTS?)